# How to assign angular setting to html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an app.js that I'm modifying and have tried everything under the sun to pull out the settings.options.chatURL.value into an html iFrame scr attribute. closest I get is pulling out an alert window but still says {{settings.options.chatURL.value}}???

```
var app=angular.module('settingsGenerator',['colorpicker.module','jdFontselect']).constant('jdFontselectConfig',{googleApiKey:'xxxxxx'});
app.controller('SettingsGeneratorCtrl',['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
  var Setting=function(type,desc,dflt,required){
    this.type=type||"String";
    this.desc=desc||"This is a setting that can be changed to a value.";
    this.required=required||false;
    this.default=dflt;
    this.value=dflt;
    this.toString=function(){
      return this.value.toString();
    };
  };
  $scope.products={
    'customizable-intro':{
      name:'Customizable Intro',
      settings:{
        options:{
          backgroundDisplay:new Setting("Radio","Do you want to display a background?","yes",true),
          backgroundType:new Setting("RadioV","Video or Image Background?","image",true),
          chatDisplay:new Setting("Radio","Do you want to display a Chat Box?","yes",true),
          chatURL:new Setting("String","Chat Box URL (stream labs)","http://example",false)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

---

```
<html>
    <div id="chat">
        <iframe id="twitchChat" src="*({{NEED URL HERE}})*">
        </iframe>
        <span id="chatURL">{{settings.options.chatURL.value}}</span>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: have you got angular in your html page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives on one of those DOM elements in order for angular to have scope over that part of the DOM like so:

Once you get Angular in scope, you will need to access your object, which you seem to be missing a few layers of, based on your code. You are accessing `$scope.settings.options.chatURL.value` and it should be `$scope.products['customizable-intro'].settings...` You can either use the full namespace every time, or simply use the `ng-init` directive to shorten it down.

Also, trying to use angular interpolation with the plain `src` attribute has been documented to not work consistently properly, and according to the angular docs, they recommend using `ng-src`. [Docs Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

```
<html ng-app="settingsGenerator">
    <div id="chat" ng-controller="SettingsGeneratorCtrl" 
      ng-init="settings = products['customizable-intro'].settings">
        <iframe id="twitchChat" ng-src="{{settings.options.chatURL.value}}"></iframe>
        <span id="chatURL">{{settings.options.chatURL.value}}</span>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: [http://friendlyneighborhoodgeeks.com/twitch/overlays/settings-generator.html](website) I tried it your way adding in the ng-controller and init still nothing

Comment: @AnthonyLester "still nothing" does not help me. What specifically happens when you run this code? What doesn't work? Do you get any error messages? Is the correct URL displayed in the chatURL span?

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute can be added dynamically to the element. The `setting` function should return a value to set it to the object keys. Refer the below code.

```js
var app = angular.module('settingsGenerator',[]);
app.controller('SettingsGeneratorCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.Setting = function(type,desc,dflt,required){
return {
  type: type||"String",
  desc: desc||"This is a setting that can be changed to a value.",
  required: required||false,
  default: dflt,
  value: dflt
  }
}
$scope.products = { 
  'customizable-intro': {
    name:'Customizable Intro',
    settings: {
      options: {
        backgroundDisplay: $scope.Setting("Radio","Do you want to display a background?","yes",true),
        backgroundType: $scope.Setting("RadioV","Video or Image Background?","image",true),
        chatDisplay: $scope.Setting("Radio","Do you want to display a Chat Box?","yes",true),
        chatURL: $scope.Setting("String","Chat Box URL (stream labs)","https://www.google.com",false)
      }}}}

$scope.al = function(){ angular.element(document.getElementById('twitchChat')).attr('src', 'http:/www.example.com')
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat" ng-app="settingsGenerator" ng-controller="SettingsGeneratorCtrl">
  <button ng-click="al()">button</button>
        <iframe id="twitchChat">
        </iframe>
        <span id="chatURL">{{products['customizable-intro'].settings.options.chatURL.value}}</span>
    </div>
```